# What to send to actionPerformed?

Tags: java, action, awt

If I call action by myself then what should I send to `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` as `e`? My logic does not use this parameter so I can send `null`, but what is sent here regularly? If action is called by button, then what it sends here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you pass 3 or 4 parts (according to the constructors for [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html)):

- the source (usually a `Component`, but can really be anything; generally the originating piece of the UI that resulted in the event being generated),
- the ID (almost always `ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED`, but could also be `ActionEvent.ACTION_FIRST` or `ActionEvent.ACTION_LAST`),
- the command string (see [`AbstractButton.getActionCommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getActionCommand%28%29)),
- and any modifiers (for example, `ActionEvent.ALT_MASK | ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK` if the user held <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> while performing the action).

The modifiers are optional, everything else is required. You can also pass a `when` for the timing of the event, but generally isn't necessary as it defaults to when the event was constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Read the doc for [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html). The constructors documentation will tell you what you want to know. For more information, you could also simply add a button and a breakpoint. Press the button and get all the details.